# How to send credentials to Angular app?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, angularjs, laravel-4

I am implementing a authentication for my `Angular app (front_end)`, I create a seperate login page for authentication which authenticates a `email` & `password` with `ajax call` on `laravel 4 (back_end)` and get a response with `tokens` and other details, and then it redirects to app with response as `query string`.

My Questions is that it is safe to redirect in a app with `query string` of access credentials, or is there any other way to prevent this?

Comment: if you want to protect credentials and the user's session token use TLS (i.e. SSL). I'd recommend keeping your credentials out of the query string: POST them instead. Attach the session token as a HTTP cookie, don't append query string (see: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Codereview-Session-Management)

Comment: I am not using `php` in angular app, so, how can i get post variable at that side ( in `angular js` )?

Comment: Use $http service built in AngularJS

Comment: i am not firing request from angular to my login page, I am sending a data from login page to angular app.

Comment: Your authentication is ultimately to your backend service, right? If your Angular app and your login page are on the same domain, then cookie is the proper authentication mechanism. If your Angular app is in a different domain, then you need to look into OAuth/OpenId/SAML proptocols.

Comment: If your entire authentication system lies inside the client then your entire authentication system can be controlled and subverted by the user. If you're dealing with sensitive data you need to store and access credentials on the server. Otherwise you should just avoid the authentication layer all together.